# How to choose correct CultureInfo so that decimal is always right

Tags: asp.net, decimal, cultureinfo

I have the following code:

```
 object obj=GetParameterValue('PARAM1');//
 decimal value=Convert.ToDecimal(obj);
```

The GetparameterValue method returns an object. Assume the value of the object is 1268.08. When I deploy my application on my own machine IIS the value is right. But if I try it on another IIS where Regional Settings is Russian I get 126808. If I replace the second line of code with the below one the number returns right:

```
 decimal value=Convert.ToDecimal(obj,new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
```

But I don't want to stick to russian culture only. I've tried InvariantCulture but it did not work, I still got 126808 instead of 1268.08. What should I do in this case?

1.Should I configure the machine where I'm going to deploy the application for my code

2.Should I write the code for some specific Culture? (Which's not much different from the first case)

3.If neither above is right, is there a better, universal way?

Comment: Do you want decimal format to be always same? Then use like you did with one selected locale e.g en_US. Don't see problem here. Also I think that better idea is to make both IIS configurations compatible with each other.

Comment: The problem is not with the format of the decimal. The problem is that with different locales selected, Convert.ToDecimal() returns two different numbers, like 126880 and 1268.80. To be more clear, one of the numbers is one hundred and twenty-six thousand eight hundred and eighty, while the other one is one thousand two hundred and sixty-eight point eight.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
```

It's the best universal way to do it.